# Using SQL query to update meta_key='_price' with value in meta_key='_regular_price'

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

In the database for every product I want to update _price with the value of _regular_price , as value of _price is less than the value of _regular_price, I have tried to use this query but didn't worked.

```
UPDATE wp_g9he6fnfw8_postmeta 
SET META_KEY._regular_price = META_KEY._price
```

I also tried to update the value like this but didn't work

```
UPDATE wp_g9he6fnfw8_postmeta 
SET _regular_price = _price
```

Where I am getting wrong. How can I copy the value of the _regular_price into _price.

Comment: The first query is trying to update a table(meta_key) which isn't referenced in the update table part of the query, the second query looks like if should work if _regular_price and _price exist in wp_g9he6fnfw8_postmeta. and can you expand on what didn't work means - do you get a syntax error or does the query run an not do as you expect?

Comment: I am getting unknown column error, How can I target _price ?

Comment: What table does _price exist in?

Comment: This is the table structure in screenshot (https://prnt.sc/m6j906) , The name of the table is wp_g9he6fnfw8_postmeta The name of the column is Meta_Key and within Meta_key column row I need to update _price value with the value of _regular_price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self join may be what you need for example

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t( postid int, meta_key varchar(20), meta_value int);

insert into t values
(1,'_regular_price',10),
(1,'_price',20);

update t t1 join t t2 on t2.postid = t1.postid and t2.meta_key = '_price'
set t1.meta_value = t2.meta_value
where t1.meta_key = '_regular_price';

select * from t;

+--------+----------------+------------+
| postid | meta_key       | meta_value |
+--------+----------------+------------+
|      1 | _regular_price |         20 |
|      1 | _price         |         20 |
+--------+----------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```